# Use fractions to solve decimal number inaccuracy

Tags: floating-point, integer, decimal, floating-accuracy, fractions

If decimals cannot be represented in binary, then why don't computers store the number as a fraction of two integers that CAN be accurately represented?

- Every time the number is used to display somewhere, it can be converted to an inaccurate float.
- Every time it is used for further calculation, you include the fraction.

This should fundamentally solve the problem of inaccuracy, but it's not all that genius, so what's wrong with the theory?

e.g. you want to store the number 0.1 and use it for further calculation. Rather than storing it as 0.1, you store it as 1/10 (so you need some more bytes to store fractions). Then, if you need to multiply it by another number, say 5, you now also multiply the error by 3. If you multiply 1/10 by 3, you get 1/10*3 = 3/10. Whenever you need to display it, 3/10 may become inaccurate. Until that time, there's no question of inaccuracy.

Comment: The floating point formats that exists are easy and fast to use with calculation, and are also easy to implement in hardware. They are also quite compact, which was even more important at the time the formats was created.

Comment: Try to compute the sum of 1/k for k less than n big enough and you will see that the size (in bits) of your denominator is something like exponential with respect to n. The floating-point format keeps constant size (in bits) for the result of such computation. Even if it is approximate, every floating-point computation is done in fixed bound storage and in fixed bound time, which is not the case for "exact" fractions.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the fact that you wouldn't be able to use irrational functions such as `sqrt` (mentioned by MSalters), you also have the problem that rationals can very easily overflow (e.g. try multiplying a couple together, or use an iterative routine like Newton's method). Of course you could use arbitrary precision integers but then they would be slow, and you would have to store those massive numbers in memory.

Comment: I wrote a BigRational type, using BigIntegers as numerator and denominator, and typically, the BigIntegers don't get very huge at all.

Comment: What were you using it for though?

Comment: I wrote it to help me calculate MacLaurin series for BigDecimal trigonometry, exponentiation, etc. with the necessary precision. But it can b used as a type of its own too. Note that this was not written in Java, I wrote BigInteger, BigDecimal and BigRational in Object Pascal (and some built-in assembler).

Answer (score 0):

Decimals just aren't important. The classical use case was money, until somebody was smart enough to realize that you can work with integral cents.

It's important to understand that reality has no preference for any base, certainly not for a base that's derived from the median number of fingers of Homo Sapiens.

As for ratio's, they too cannot represent `sqrt(2)` or `arctan(1)`. And those *are* the type of numbers which appear in reality.